# F# linq query and nullable casting

Tags: linq, nhibernate, f#

I have the following `C#` `LINQ` query that runs against nhibernate:

```
var items = new int[] { 1,2};

var c11 = session.Query<Parent>()
   .Where(p => p.Children.Any(c => items.Contains((int)c.FIELD))).ToList();
```

In this case `c.FIELD` is a `Nullable<int>` and when I check the *IL* code casting to int is transformed to `Expression.Convert`

How can I translate this `F#`, since with `F#` I can't cast a `Nullable<int>` to `int`. I can only call op_Explicit but that turns into a different Expression not to `Expression.Convert`. I am stuck at this point.

Comment: why not use `c.FIELD.GetValueOrDefault()` or `c.FIELD.Value`?

Comment: Because they are translated to Expression.Invoke rather than Expression.Convert,  and NHibernate wants Expression.Convert

Comment: If it can handle an `(int)` cast but not a `.Value` on a Nullable then it's a bug in the NHibernate LINQ implementation.

Comment: I would say it is a missing feature. In any case I am looking for a workaround if you call it that way.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to convert `items` to `seq<Nullable<int>>` and not cast `FIELD` at all? It wouldn't change anything in the example above, I'm not sure if it would fit your situation though. It *should* work with NHibernate though...

Comment: what about 'items.Contains(int c.Field)' ?

Comment: @desco: That worked! Thanks. What syntax is this? I am not so good in F# yet any docs related to that ?

Comment: @emperon `int: 'A -> int` is a function doing casts to int (actually an int constructor)

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are looking for is [Operators.int<^T> Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Ee370576)

> Converts the argument to signed 32-bit integer. This is a direct conversion for all primitive numeric types. For strings, the input is converted using Parse with InvariantCulture settings. Otherwise the operation requires an appropriate static conversion method on the input type.

```
query { for parent in session.Query<Parent>() do
        where (parent.Children.Any (fun c -> items.Contains (int c.FIELD)))
        select parent }
```